# JavaFX, switching panes in a root window and retaining memory

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller, javafx, scenebuilder

As stated in the title, I have fxml files, I have a UI that is set up with three labels/buttons up top and the lower half of the window has a pane. Every time a label/button is clicked, the pane must switch to that corresponding fxml file. So in other words, the pane must always be in the same position, kind of like a tabbed layout but without tabs.

I know I can achieve this with just loading a new instance of an fxml file but, I want to avoid that because when a user click on a tab he previously was on, he should be able to see his earlier input.

I have some main.java that starts the program. Some controller.java that controls the UI when it is first loaded, and some fxml file corresponding to that initial view. How can I go about implementing this transition functionality? P.S. I am very novice at JavaFX.

Comment: You want to switch pane at a click of a button ?

Comment: yes but that switch must not delete input in the previous pane when going to the next. User should be able to go back and forth and see the same input. Also, it is more like a tab design if you can imagine that. But I would prefer not to use tabs.

Comment: Just load all three FXML files once and keep references to the UIs that are loaded (and the controllers if you need them).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how you can achieve it. 
It can of course be implemented using `FXML` :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageTest extends Application{

    private Pane pane1, pane2, mainPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        stage.setTitle("Switch Panes");
        Button button1 = new Button("Show Pane 1");
        button1.setOnAction(e -> showPane1());
        Button button2 = new Button("Show Pane 2");
        button2.setOnAction(e -> showPane2());

        HBox buttonsPane = new HBox(5.);
        buttonsPane.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2);

        pane1 = getPane("PANE ONE");
        pane2 = getPane("PANE TWO");
        mainPane = new StackPane(pane1);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(buttonsPane);
        root.setCenter(mainPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    private void showPane1() {
        mainPane.getChildren().clear();
        mainPane.getChildren().add(pane1);
    }

    private void showPane2() {
        mainPane.getChildren().clear();
        mainPane.getChildren().add(pane2);
    }

    private Pane getPane(String txt) {

        VBox pane = new VBox();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(new TextArea(txt+" add text here: "));
        return pane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but my fxml file is linked only with the controller class. So I will need to handle buttons for switching in the controller class and it won't let me do this.

Comment: Can you actually demonstrate this with FXML files?